# linux ascii to utf-16 (then sha1 and base64) encode

Tags: c++, c, linux

We have a communication protocol that requires us to Base64 Encoded a SHA1 hash of a UTF-16 encoded password.  We have been given Java, javascript, and visual basic examples however we are running under Linux (redhat)

the provided test string: `TESTED@8691`
the final output: `rBbBKqbJodT5awZal/CSCYF/sFo=`

I have tried

```
iconv_t conv = iconv_open("UTF-16LE","ASCII"); // open succeeds
char *from_string=strdup("TESTED@8691");
size_t from_length=strlen(from_string);
size_t to_length=from_length*3;
size_t original_to_length=to_length;

char *to_string=(char*)calloc(1,to_length);
int convert_return=iconv(conv,&from_string,&from_length,&to_string,&to_length);
// convert_return is 0 indicating success, to_length is 11, from_length is 0
```

run sha1 and base64 encoding on to_string with a length of 22
resulting output: `GCXe7HMDoq/NRqo1WWYJDDYZzP0=`

If I loop through to_string I get:

```
for (int i=0; i<original_to_length-to_length; ++i) {
   printf("to_string %d = %x",i,to_string[i]);  
}

output:
to_string 0 = 0
to_string 1 = 0
to_string 2 = 0
to_string 3 = 0
to_string 4 = 0
to_string 5 = 0
to_string 6 = 0
to_string 7 = 0
to_string 8 = 0
to_string 9 = 0
to_string 10 = 0
to_string 11 = 0
to_string 12 = 0
to_string 13 = 0
to_string 14 = 21
to_string 15 = 0
to_string 16 = 0
to_string 17 = 0
to_string 18 = 4
to_string 19 = 7e
to_string 20 = 13
to_string 21 = e
```

Here is the javascript conversion:

```
function str2rstr_utf16le(input)
{
   var output = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    output += String.fromCharCode( input.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF,
                              (input.charCodeAt(i) >>> 8) & 0xFF);

   return output;
}
```

What am I missing?
Thank You

Comment: Are you sure you picked the right UTF-16?

Comment: I am quite surprised to see 22 lines printed, considering that you're looping 11 times (original_to_length==33, to_length==22).

Comment: sorry about my mistyping....to_length becomes 11 so the difference is 22

Comment: The dump of `to_string` is clearly not UTF-16 so that explains the wrong output. I don't know enough about `iconv` to provide a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked using a shell script and it seems the result you were given is indeed correct, as long as you assume UTF-16 to be UTF-16LE (Little Endian):

```
$ echo -e $(echo -n 'TESTED@8691' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le | sha1sum - | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]+' | sed -r 's/(..)/\\x\1/g') | tr -d '\n'  | base64
rBbBKqbJodT5awZal/CSCYF/sFo=
```

For Big-Endian, I get `YrAwH9v3d88gjvsg0Hypu2Cfjc8=` which is not your result, so I think endianness isn't the issue here.

The [man page for iconv(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv) states:

```
The  iconv  function converts one multibyte character at a
time, and for  each  character  conversion  it  increments
*inbuf  and  decrements *inbytesleft by the number of con­
verted input bytes, it increments *outbuf  and  decrements
*outbytesleft by the number of converted output bytes, and
it updates the conversion state contained in cd.
```

This suggests that `iconv` modifies your target buffer pointer (`to_string`) - that's why you pass it `&to_string`, not `to_string` itself. So, probably you need to subtract the number of bytes that were processed from `to_string` after `iconv` and before the further operations (SHA1 and BASE64).

Comment: Your sed pipeline appends a newline; that’s what the `K` is.

Comment: A simpler way to verify the result is this Python: `hashlib.sha1('TESTED@8691'.encode('utf-16le')).digest().encode('base64')`

Comment: I knew the answer was there to be found if I only looked at it enough.  I read the man page at least a dozen times and always just read right over the "increments *outbuf" section without giving it proper consideration.  When I keep the original pointer location (or back up based on the modified one) then the to_string dump is correct and everything else falls into place.  Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia.

> For Internet  protocols, IANA has approved "UTF-16", "UTF-16BE", and
>   "UTF-16LE" as the names for these encodings. (The names are case
>   insensitive.) The aliases UTF_16 or UTF16  may be meaningful in some
>   programming languages or software applications, but they are not
>   standard names in Internet protocols.

I imagine that the `UTF-16BE` and `UTF-16LE` are Big Endian and Little Endian encodings, repsectively.  Odds are excellent that you are using UTF-16, but with the "wrong" endian-ness for your input data.

Edit: A quick search confirms my suspicions [UTF-16LE is "UTF-16, Little Endian"](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/UTF-16-UTF-16LE-Encoding.html).  Odds are excellent that your input data was Big Endian.  If that is the case, all of your "high end" UTF-16 bytes are being placed in the "low end" byte position (and vice-versa).

See if you get your expected result with "UTF-16BE".